# Mapping Keyboard Shortcuts in Word (vba) KeyBindings.Add KeyCategory: = wdKeyCategoryCommand, Command: = "..."

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good day.

Someone has a list of the commands that can be assigned a keyboard shortcut using the function:

```
KeyBindings.Add KeyCategory: = wdKeyCategoryCommand, Command: = "..."
```

I want to assign a shortcut to decreasing French indentation, but I only see the command for its increase: `Command: = "HangingIndent"`

Thank you. Greetings.

Comment: Is your question about how to do key bindings? About which Word command produces a particular result so you can do a key binding to that command? I am ignorant and do not know what "decreasing French indentation" means. Please expand and clarify your question.

Comment: In Word, it is often easier to assign keyboard shortcuts through the user interface, rather than through code. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330

Answer (score 1):

Choose **Developer>Macros**. Change the *Macros in* dropdown to **Word commands**. The complete list of available command names is displayed.

If you need to set specific indentation amounts, you'll have to write a simple macro instead of relying on Word's preset indentation values.

But it's probably better to avoid VBA altogether. Instead of relying on local formatting (which a Word command or macro would do), create a typestyle with your preferred indentation and apply that to the text. That's a better practice in Word and easy to update later if you change your mind about the amount of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is precisely that, that the command related to the decrease of the French indentation does not appear in the list of Word commands. What I need to know is what the said command is called. After a lot of thinking I found a command to list all the keyboard shortcuts in the active document: `Application.Run MacroName: =" CommandList"` and this allowed me to find what I'm looking for: `RemoveHangingIndent`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should edit your question to clarify it - and don't use the answer option for this.